# Bizarre colors doing phong shading on ray-tracer

Tags: c++, raytracing, shading

I recently added support to phong shading in a cpu ray-tracer and the colors are all messed-up: 
[image]

If I just do diffuse: [image]

Some relevant code:

```
 Vec3f camera_dir (xx_array[x],py,scene->getCameraDirZ());
  camera_dir.normalize ();

 Vec3f hit_normal = (1 - u - v) * vert1 + u * vert2 + v * vert3;
 hit_normal.normalize ();

 Vec3f light_ray_dir (current.pos - intersection);
 float squared_length = light_ray_dir.normalize_return_squared_lenght ();

 Vec3f reflected = light_ray_dir - 2 * (light_ray_dir * hit_normal) * hit_normal;
 reflected.normalize();
 specular_color += light_intensity * std::pow (std::max(0.f,reflected*camera_dir),mat.ns);
 final_color = diffuse_color * mat.ks; + specular_color * mat.kd; (if is only difusse * mat.ks or mat.kd it produces the second image)
```

Some possibly relevant information

The four last lines are consecutive, although the last one happens outside the for loop responsible for doing the shading calculations for each light.

The two "hit_normal" lines happens earlier, they are before the aforementioned loop start.

The first two happens in the beginning of the ray-tracer, in earlier lines of the two for loops responsible for the image pixels.

if I swap the reflected calculation from

```
 Vec3f reflected = light_ray_dir - 2 * (light_ray_dir * hit_normal) * hit_normal;
```

to:

```
 Vec3f reflected = 2 * (light_ray_dir * hit_normal) * hit_normal - light_ray_dir;
```

image only changes slightly:

[image]

As code shows, all three component vectors (hit_normal, reflected, light_ray_dir, camera_dir) are normalized.

So I ask for suggestions of how to debug the issue, suggestions of what can be wrong. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: This question could be good, but it seems to be missing the full code that you're using. Creating a [mcve] is important. :)

Comment: @grooveplex The issue here (and in another cases) is that I can't think in another way to do that than to link to the full source. I can't really do a small program than do enough to reproduce the issue. Plus would take too long.